# How to format datetime-local to read date with more than three milliseconds numbers

Tags: html, angular, database, datetime-format

I am using the html datetime-local attribute in my edit form, is there a way to change the format so that it can display database timestamp string: 2017-02-09 14:00:31.256382. I know that datetime-local works with .000 milliseconds but is it posible to make it show .000000?

With this string: 2017-02-09 14:00:31.256 - my edit form datetime shows: 2017-02-09 14:00:31.256

but with: 2017-02-09 14:00:31.256382 - the edit form datetime shows: yyyy-mm-dd --:--

Is there a way to get six positions to work.